# Maker.js export dxf string as a file to user desired location

Tags: javascript, dxf, maker-js

I'm using [maker.js](https://maker.js.org/docs/exporting/) from microsoft to create svgs and maker.js also allow to [export](https://maker.js.org/docs/exporting/#DXF) the models to dxf string.
I'm able to get dxf string from it.
I want to make dxf file from dxf string and save in user desired location or default download location.

#### Question

How do I create a file and write in it using a string and save it with extension .dxf using javascript.

Comment: You can't do that with JS. You can create the file, then ask your user to open a download dialog so that they can select the location and filename and the extension. That's all you can do with JS, as it doesn't have access to the local filesystem.

Comment: So, you are using `maker.js`?
Please add that to the question's tags.
Thank you.

Comment: @iAmOren I was not able to add that! because there is no maker.js tag available

Comment: Ok, thanks for trying!
(I filter out libraries when looking for questions to answer = I don't want to learn libraries = I want to do as much as I can with vanilla so I won't be held hostage in the future...)

Answer (score 2):

Generally a user has to initiate a download, easiest way I'm aware of is a href to a data url. In React you can render that link as:

```
<a 
    download="result.dxf"
    href={`data:application/octet-stream;base64,${btoa(dxfString)}`}
>
  Download your DXF
</a>
```

Where `dxfString` is a the value returned by makerjs.

[Demo of this code](https://scriptcad.com/paulftw/involuteGear) in production

[HTML only version in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/paulftw/hs5qLmja/)

Depending on your framework you'll need a different syntax for changing `href` of a link. `btoa` is a standard function in all modern browsers.